# How to manage retry policy for specific response? (Robospice)

Tags: android, okhttp, robospice, retrypolicy

I would like to achieve managing custom retry policy in my application. By default it does 3 retries after requset failure, but I don't want to retry for HTTP 400 responce. How can I do this?

Comment: what are you using ? volley , asynk or else ?

Comment: @RjzSatvara I'm using Robospice